# Convert string to double using custom numpunct doesn't work as expected

Tags: c++, locale

I am trying to convert a string to a double using a custom `numpunct`.  I want the conversion to fail if the string is not in a currency-style format - e.g. `1,000,000.0`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class ThousandCommaSeparator: public std::numpunct<char>
{
public:
    ThousandCommaSeparator(){}
protected:
    virtual char do_decimal_point() const { return '.'; }
    virtual char do_thousands_sep() const { return ','; }
    virtual string_type do_grouping() const { return "\3";}
};

int main()
{
    istringstream ss("2015/05/03");
    ss.imbue(locale(cout.getloc(),new ThousandCommaSeparator));

    double output;

    if (ss >> output)
    {
        cout << "Success: " << output << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Failure: " << output << endl;
    }
}
```

I want the above to fail, but it always succeeds, and sets the value of output to 2015.  I'm guessing I'm using `numpunct` incorrectly, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction!

Comment: But how is `2015` not a valid double?

Comment: wouldn't a regex better fit the task of validating against an expected format?

Comment: I was trying to avoid using a regex if possible - it would absolutely suit for this problem, but would be noticeably slower over millions of runs.  Slower but correct is better than faster but wrong though, so it may be that I need to go down that route!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thousands separators in an input stream are optional. If they are present, they must be placed correctly, but they don't have to be present.

Thus, `2015` is a valid input to convert to an number regardless of `std::numpunct`.

Comment: Ah, I thought that using a custom numpunct would help invalidate anything that wasn't covered by it.  If that's not the case, then it's the wrong tool for this job.  Thanks for your answer.